# Is there a way to use Fabric.js and p5.js on the same canvas

Tags: javascript, canvas, fabricjs, p5.js

I'm working on a project and would like to use both p5.js and fabric.js on the same canvas. I need the functionality of fabric.js to drag around pictures on the canvas and p5.js to dynamically draw lines between the pictures as they're being dragged. I'm not sure if this is possible because it seems like both have their own separate canvas creation functions

p5.js

```
createCanvas(100, 50);
```

fabric.js

```
canvas = new fabric.Canvas('c');
```

The fabric line class seems a little too rigid to accomplish the effect I'm after, so I'm looking for either an idea for a workaround or a different library that would be better for drawing dynamic lines on a fabric canvas.

Answer (score 0):

It is not possible to combine both of them with one canvas element. These libraries take full control of the canvas of reference. Even if you were able to initialise both libraries on the same canvas element you will loose whatever was displayed by p5.js on the first FarbicJS `canvas.renderAll()` function call.

I don't know what exactly is your problem, but as an alternative I think you could try to have two canvases on top of each other (since the canvas element is invisible by default). One running on FabricJS and one on p5.js and somehow interact with each other. But, that will add some additional complexity.